# How can I sort an array having elements as string representing amount of money with their symbols like 62B and 51M ? I need to sort this money amount

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

**I searched online but was unable to find a solution. Please help.**

Suppose my array is :

```
['633.7B', '527M', 2.1B', '25K', '60M', '32B', '85k', '147.2M']
```

It should yield **output in ascending** as:

```
['25K', '85K', '60M', '147.2M', '527M', '2.1B', '32B', '633.7B']
```

Comment: In your compare function, convert both strings to numbers and return the comparison of those.

Comment: What have you found in your search that was not a solution? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Actually, I was building a Cryptocurrency tracker. I have static data with me which I'm displaying in a table. In the table, there is a column named"Mkt Cap" which contains the market value in billions(B) and in millions(M). I wanted to make that column sortable by clicking the column header. 
So I had an array of objects with me [like this](https://pastebin.com/bafaPPh1) and my solution was [this](https://pastebin.com/LZCYwfFR) but my solution was wrong. Please help.

Comment: @TarunSingh, have a look at my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
const numberFormat = {
  'K': 1000,
  'M': 1000000,
  'B': 1000000000
}

const oldArr = ['633.7B', '527M', '2.1B', '25K', '60M', '32B', '85K', '147.2M']

const newArr =
  oldArr
  .sort((a, b) =>
    a.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '') * numberFormat[a.slice(-1)] - b.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '') * numberFormat[b.slice(-1)]
  )

console.log('newArr', newArr)
```

Steps to understand:

- First we created a simple relation between numbers figures and its related value
- Then we sorted our array doing a regex to replace everything which isn't numbers or dots with `''` (empty)
- Then we multiplied this extracted number by its correspondent number ( million, trillion or billion )
- And that's it, just subtract one by the other and you'll have your array correctly sorted

Answer (score 0):

Ideas are as follows:

1. Convert your string array of numbers to the exact number.
2. Compare numbers in between in the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

Here is the working example:

```js
var numbers = ['633.7B', '527M', '2.1B', '25K', '60M', '32B', '85k', '147.2M'];

function stringToNumber(s) {
    var u = s.slice(-1);
    if (u === "k")
        return s.slice(0, -1) * 1000;
    else if (u === "m")
        return s.slice(0, -1) * 1000000;
    else if (u === "b")
        return s.slice(0, -1) * 1000000000;
    return s;
}

numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
    var n1 = stringToNumber(a.toLowerCase());
    var n2 = stringToNumber(b.toLowerCase());
    return n1 - n2;
});

console.log(...numbers);
```

**Update: According to your array, your sort will be like this as above**

```js
const array2 = [
    { 'Mkt Cap': '633.7B' },
    { 'Mkt Cap': '527M' },
    { 'Mkt Cap': '2.1B' },
    { 'Mkt Cap': '25K' },
    { 'Mkt Cap': '60M' },
    { 'Mkt Cap': '32B' },
    { 'Mkt Cap': '85K' },
    { 'Mkt Cap': '147.2M' }];

function stringToNumber(s) {
    var u = s.slice(-1);
    if (u === "k")
        return s.slice(0, -1) * 1000;
    else if (u === "m")
        return s.slice(0, -1) * 1000000;
    else if (u === "b")
        return s.slice(0, -1) * 1000000000;
    return s;
}

array2.sort(function (a, b) {
    var n1 = stringToNumber(a['Mkt Cap'].toLowerCase());
    var n2 = stringToNumber(b['Mkt Cap'].toLowerCase());
    return n1 - n2;
});

console.log(array2);
```